# loading controller.js files on demand vs minify all controllers and attach once

Tags: angularjs, design-patterns

I am new to angularjs development so not sure which approach is best suited here. I am working on a large scale application and day by day we are adding more and more controllers into it. I want to know which approach is better in terms of performance and maintenance.

```
1) Load controller.js file only when required like using resolveRoute approach.
```

or

```
2) Minify all controllers and load it once at the start of application.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should go for option 2. 
Especially if you are just starting with AngularJS .
There is no way in angular itself to cater for the dynamic loading of scripts.

It is possible, but not an easy road to go.
And if your application is not extremely big (200Kb minified&concatenated or smaller of your own code) it probably is not worth the extra work.